# SQL, find min and max of any symbol that max is more greater than 20 percent and newer from min

Tags: mysql, sql

I need maximum and minimum in `IBP` column of `live_filter` table for each symbol, that occurred in the last 20 minute and the maximum is newer and greater than 20 percent of minimum. I've tried this script but can not figure out why it is listing maximum occurred before minimum?

```
 SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT i18 as symbol, MAX(ibp)/min_ibp AS ibp_rate
 FROM live_filter 
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT i18 AS min_i18, Min(ibp) AS min_ibp, ct AS min_ct FROM live_filter 
    GROUP BY i18 
 ) AS min_table
 ON i18= min_table.min_i18
  GROUP BY i18 ORDER BY ibp_rate DESC) AS t1 
 WHERE t1.ibp_rate > 1.2;
```

table would be like this:

- ct: #creation time of log
- ibp: # some values
- i18: # symbol name

EDIT:
as @strawberry commented I've add a MRE:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS live_filter (
    ibp double,
    ct datetime,
    i18 varchar(50)
);
insert into live_filter (ibp, ct, i18) VALUES
('0.303', '2021-01-16 11:59:46', 'skhnd'),
('0.137', '2021-01-16 12:01:46', 'skhnd'),
('0.903', '2021-01-16 11:57:46', 'sds'),
('0.203', '2021-01-16 11:55:46', 'sds');
```

desired result is just  like this:

|symbol |   ibp_rate       |

|sds    | 4.448275862068965|

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8edb35/1)

EDIT2: desired result is to return no row because min comes after max.
EDIT3: change MRE to MCRE !!

Comment: @Strawberry I've added a MRE

Comment: I don't see the desired result

Comment: @Strawberry, I've added desired result!

Comment: A desired result that returns no rows is not helpful. While MCRE is 'M' (minimal), it's not 'C' (complete). And nor, in any meaningful sense is it 'R' (reproducible).

Comment: @Strawberry I've changed MRE to MCRE!!

Comment: Where does 4.448275862068965| come from?

Comment: @Strawberry 0.903/0.203